# Generating PDFs in multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, concurrency, jboss

The goal is to make a pdf-generating service. The service is avaiable via simple servlet.

Assumptions made are such, that the service is supposed to be running on multiple load-balanced servers (e.g. Tomcat instances), with each server running its manually created threads, which generate PDFs. Each request has to be written to a database, and its pdf status has to be updated throughout the whole process, like:

- QUEUED at first
- IN PROGRESS when the pdf generation starts
- PROCESSED after a pdf is created

Another assumption is that each Tomcat instance which got the request is responsible for generating the document. The whole solution must be persistent across restarts, so each server instance needs to store its task queue somehow (in a file for example?).

One might think that the whole process might be synchronized with the database, but IMHO polling a database for new PDF requests can be time-consuming.

Any ideas, hints?

Assumptions are flexible, so if anyone, who happens to come with some good out-of-assumptions solution, is kindly asked to share his/her ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For queuing, use a message bus like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ with persistent queues.

1. Provide a request servlet which puts a request on a message queue and sets a QUEUED status for the request in the database.
2. Use listeners (in the Tomcat servlet container or not) to  listen for messages on the queue.
3. When the listeners detect a new message, they pull it off and start PDF generation, and set the IN PROGRESS status on the message.
4. When the listeners are done processing, they set PROCESSED status on the job, ACK the message to totally remove it from the queue, and move on to the next one.

If a listener dies before it is done processing the message, the message will be un-ACK'd and available for other listeners to process.  Another listener will pick it up, set the status to  IN PROGRESS again, and complete it.

Comment: i wanted to avoid using queues like that, as it seemed a bit of over-complication to me, but apparently it's unavoidable with provided requirements. thanks for your response.